# A bug during CIRQ installation

Tags: programming, cirq

I had the following problem with an installation of the Cirq.

When I typed `python -m pip install cirq`, I got the following line:

"**Cannot uninstall 'sympy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.**"

The source of this issue was in a new version of 'sympy' (1.23 instead of 1.22).

I found a simple solution to remove 'sympy' 
`conda uninstall sympy`

and then wrote this code `python -m pip install cirq` again. After that, everything works fine.

Could you correct this bug in the future?

Comment: It looks like this should be an issue on Cirq's github repository ( github.com/quantumlib/cirq/issues ) instead of a question on stack exchange. But also it looks like this is not a bug with cirq but rather a bad interaction between conda and pip.

Comment: I think, Craig Gidney,  you right, but I write this issue for developers in order to fix the problem because it was a recommendation on the cite.

Comment: Hi Elijah - both Craig and I are developers on Cirq. Do you still have this issue?

Comment: Balint, thank you for your reply. I managed this problem by using Google Collab, where there is no such a problem.

Comment: Thank you, it sounds like something might have been specific to your environment. Do you mind closing the question in that case? I think it is not that valuable to leave it here as you have no cirq version mentioned in it, so it is very hard to reproduce for people who would try to help!

Comment: Balint, yes I do. I think my issue was solved, so we can close the question.